How to append excel file with dataframe from column D?
I have Excel file out_file and DataFrame dfSave.
I want this DataFrame to append Excel starting from column D.
I think sometimes in this file can appear some formatting like bgcolor or "Wrap text", hope this doesn't affect, cause openpyxl starts to append only from "virgin" rows.
This is what I have now, but like I said, I want it to start at column D and after rows that filled in, ignoring formatting.
wb = load_workbook(filename=out_file)
    ws = wb["Sheet 1"]
    for r in dataframe_to_rows(dfSave, index=False, header=False):
        ws.append(r)
    wb.save(out_file)

Image of the initial state of the table
Image of the final state of the table

Openpyxl append always adds to the next unused row i.e. the first row after the last row that contains any value in any column. It starts appending from column A if a list is used, There is no way to change the behaviour of writing to the next unused row. If you want to start inserting your values from column D, the list would need to be padded for columns A - C. Or you change to a dictionary and set the key to the column you want the value to be inserted in to.

@moken , It’s not necessary for me to use openpyxl, I just attached an option of what I tried and what didn’t work for me. If you now how to deal with my problem, then help me please.

You can use Pandas ExcelWriter and to_excel and just write the whole Dataframe to the Excel Sheet in one go. For the ExcelWriter use Openpyxl as the Engine in append mode and set if_sheet_exist=overlay. Set the startrow= &,startcol= to the row and column you want to insert the dataframe at in the to_excel command

@moken , i tried this one too, problem was that i didn't know startrow, it's always different

Thats OK you can still use Openpyxl max_row to get the last used row for the sheet you are writing to at the time of writing. See the code example in the answer

You can use openpyxl max row to get the last used row and then write the dataframe.
import pandas as pd

...
def maxrow(ws):
    max_row = 1
    if ws._cells:
        rows = set()
        for mr_coord, mr_cell in ws._cells.items():
            if mr_cell.value is not None:
                rows.update((mr_coord[0],))
        max_row = max(rows)

    return max_row


excel_file = 'out_file.xlsx'
sheet = 'Sheet1'
with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file,
                    engine='openpyxl',
                    mode='a',
                    if_sheet_exists='overlay'
                    ) as writer:

    dfSave.to_excel(writer,
                    sheet_name=sheet,
                    startrow=maxrow(writer.sheets[sheet])+1  # Get last used row for the Sheet
                    startcol=3,  # Column D (A is column 0)
                    index=False,
                    header=False
                    )


Thank you for the quick response, but this still doesn't work for me because .max_row takes formatted cells into account and new text starts with untouched ones. I think only option for me is to read this file with pd and na_filter and use df.shape[0] as startrow

OK, I don't know what you mean by .max_row takes formatted cells into account and new text starts with untouched ones. Openpyxl max_row is the same row +1 that append would insert to. With the code above you can directly set startrow= to dfSave.shape[0] but not sure how that helps you. Also writer.sheets[sheet] is the Openpyxl worksheet object so you can 'find' anything on the Sheet as the indicator for startrow.  Anyway, for for the info provided and questions asked these were the options.

In this Excel file there are cells that are marked with "Wrap text", and for some reason max_row consider them as not empty. I don't want to set startrow= dfSave.shape[0], i want to set shape[0] to dataframe of Excel file to get startrow

I posted my answer, see what I meant

OK,. You can make your own max row function with added criteria check and use that instead. Updated the example code.

This is how i deal with my problem:
I read whole file to DataFrame just to get max length, because max_row consider formatted cells as not empty
out_df = pd.read_excel(out_file, engine = "openpyxl", header = None, na_filter = False)
startingcol = 3
sheet_name = 'Sheet 1'
with pd.ExcelWriter(out_file,engine='openpyxl',mode='a',if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
                dfSave.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=out_df.shape[0], startcol=startingcol, index=False, header=False)

